# How to find a file which contains characters and extension in recurse mode in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, include, filenames, file-extension

I try to find all the file which contains $var and end with ".log" and I need it to be Recursive

I tried this

```
 $logDirectoryPath = $Directory + "\*"       
Get-ChildItem -Path $logDirectoryPath -Include *$iniContent["Search"]["FileWith"]*, *.log -Recurse -File -Name | ForEach-Object {
                $lbox_files.Items.Add($_)  # we add file to a list
            }
```

But this command return every single files regardless of $var and Recurse seems disable :/

the file look like this : foo_test.log

another file : \user\foo_1.log

(PS : by $var I mean it depends of $iniContent["Search"]["FileWith"] value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all files by this comand:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\" -Recurse -File -Filter "*$var*.log"
```

It's return all files in folder that contain in name `$var` and ends with `".log"`

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I did this and it works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory  -Filter *.log -Recurse -File -Name | ForEach-Object {
            $fileWith = $iniContent["Search"]["FileWith"]
            if ($_ -like '*{0}*' -f $fileWith) {
                $lbox_files.Items.Add($_)  # we add the file name to a list
            }
        }
```

If there is a better way to do it, feel free to post it too ;)